# Date format in Talend

Tags: parsing, date, datetime, talend

I am facing an issue with Talend dates. I have tried several solutions but still an "unparseable date" error persists.

My date format is of the form : 24/12/2013 16:25:47.328000000

I have tried:

- `TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX",row1.REGISTERED_ON,true)`,
- `TalendDate.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss",row1.REGISTERED_ON,true)`

but still I get that same error.

Can anyone help shed some light please?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Talend, but you say

> My date format is likewise : **24/12/2013** 16:25:47.328000000

and

> I have tried
>
> TalendDate.parseDate("**yyyy-MM-dd**'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX",row1.REGISTERED_ON,true),
>
> TalendDate.parseDate("**yyyy-MM-dd**'T'HH:mm:ss",row1.REGISTERED_ON,true)

but the date you specify is in **dd/MM/yyyy** format. I imagine that's the cause of your problems.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but, its not really that. I have tried with dd/MM/yyyy as well and I still have that same error.

Comment: Do you still get the error if you drop the fractional part of the second and try to parse "24/12/2013 16:25:47" with, say, "`dd-MM-yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss`"?

Comment: @GaspardGabriel - can you get any more information from the "unparseable date" error? Also, in my first comment I meant to say: ...try to parse "24/12/2013 16:25:47" with, say, "`dd/MM/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss`"?

Comment: I have tried some conversions on the date as per below and it seems to almost fit my needs row1.REGISTERED_ON.equals("")?null:TalendDate.parseDate("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss",StringHandling.LEFT(StringHandling.EREPLACE(row1.REGISTERED_ON,"/","-"),19) ,true).  Issue now is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "", though the source does not contain any empty field for the date column

Answer (score 1):

I am Able to parse given string date using below format, below statement should work for you,

```
Input String "24/12/2013 16:25:47.328000000" 
Format: "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSS"

System.out.println(TalendDate.parseDate("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSS", "24/12/2013 16:25:47.328000000"));
```

See more formats on ["How to parse String to Date"](http://dwetl.com/2015/01/16/convert-string-to-date/)

Answer (score 1):

to manage date in talend what i prefer to do is 
1) set data type of your_date_column to string in your input file
2) parse your_date_column at the time of mapping using
   new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(your_date_column)
3) set data type of our output_date_column to Date with date pattern :-   "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

Hope it will Work :)